# How to make popup on click on button, but one single button 2 text and 2 popup using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Hi Friends there is a single button but the text will change for the button if you click on it,

what i need is if i click button1 one popup should come and on the popup if i click ok the button should change to button2

on click on button2 another pop up should come. this is the functionality.

Here fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ljrpd/23/ Here i implemented one button two text on toggle

**SCRIPT**

```
  var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function () {
 })
 app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
 $scope.toggle = true;

 $scope.$watch('toggle', function(){
 $scope.toggleText = $scope.toggle ? 'Button1' : 'Button2';
  })
  })
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: if i click that button1 a popup should come if i click yes to popup then the button should change to Button2 and again a popup should come as yes and no

Comment: No, that is not your question. That is what you want to implement. Your question would be about _which specific detail of your implementation so far does not work and why_. You are basically asking: please do my work for me.

Comment: sorry :( I am just learning things so ...

Comment: We all start and we all learn, that is perfectly ok. I am not trying to make fun of you or anything. Just take your attempt so far and ask which step you don't understand.

Comment: what actually is i have did one functionality in angular and one more functionality is adding in this so i find very difficult do it in angular so i want already done functionality in angular and this using jQuery if possible. i dont know how to do this in onclick of that button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69505/discussion-between-manoji-stack-and-arkascha).